# Kusto: Apply function on multiple column values during bag_unpack

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

**Given** a dynamic field, say, `milestones`, it has value like: `{"ta": 1655859586546, "tb": 1655859586646}`,

**How do I** print a table with **columns like "ta", "tb" etc**, with the single row as `unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(tolong(taValue))`, `unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(tolong(tbValue))` etc.

I figured that I'll need to write a function that I can call, so I created this:-

```
let f = view(a:string ){
unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(tolong(a))
};
```

I can use this function with a `normal` column as:- `project f(columnName)`.

However, in this case, its a dynamic field, and the number of items in the list is large, so I do not want to enter the fields manually. This is what I have so far.

```
log_table
| take 1
| evaluate bag_unpack(milestones, "m_") // This gives me fields as columns
// | project-keep m_* // This would work, if I just wanted the value, however, I want `view(columnValue)
| project-keep f(m_*) // This of course doesn't work, but explains the idea.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) operator

```
// Generate data sample. Not part of the solution.
let log_table = materialize(range record_id from 1 to 10 step 1 | mv-apply range(1, 1 + rand(5), 1) on (summarize milestones = make_bag(pack_dictionary(strcat("t", make_string(to_utf8("a")[0] + toint(rand(26)))), 1600000000000 + rand(60000000000)))));
// Solution Starts here.
log_table
|   mv-apply kv = milestones on 
    (
            extend k = tostring(bag_keys(kv)[0]) 
        |   extend v = unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(tolong(kv[k]))
        |   summarize milestones = make_bag(pack_dictionary(k, v))
    )
|   evaluate bag_unpack(milestones)
```

| record_id | ta | tb | tc | td | te | tf | tg | th | ti | tk | tl | tm | to | tp | tr | tt | tu | tw | tx | tz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2021-07-06T20:24:47.767Z |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  | 2021-05-09T07:21:08.551Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2022-07-28T20:57:16.025Z |  | 2022-07-28T14:21:33.656Z |  |  | 2020-11-09T00:54:39.71Z |  | 2020-12-22T00:30:13.463Z |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2021-12-07T11:07:39.204Z |  | 2022-05-16T04:33:50.002Z |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2021-10-20T12:19:27.222Z |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  | 2022-01-31T23:24:07.305Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2021-01-20T17:38:53.21Z |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  | 2022-04-27T22:41:15.643Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2022-01-22T08:30:08.995Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2021-09-30T08:58:46.47Z |  |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |  |  | 2022-03-14T13:41:10.968Z |  |  |  |  | 2022-03-26T10:45:19.56Z |  |  |  |  |  | 2022-08-06T16:50:37.003Z |  |  |  |  |
| 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2021-03-03T11:02:02.217Z | 2021-02-28T09:52:24.327Z |  |  |  |  | 2021-04-09T07:08:06.985Z |  |  | 2020-12-28T20:18:04.973Z |
| 9 | 2022-02-17T04:55:35.468Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 2022-08-02T14:44:15.414Z | 2021-03-24T10:22:36.138Z | 2020-12-17T01:14:40.652Z |  | 2022-01-30T12:45:54.28Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2022-03-31T02:29:43.114Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5VSwWrDMAy9B/IPIiebdU07WBmMnXfbpcdSgpuoqbFjB1sJ7ejHT24bsh2nS5B4T+/pOWUJn+gwKEJoFCmIqustLuHLE/QqEPgj0AkhejuQ9m6ZZxYJrG8rUgeL8AEdk4NWVn+jCMq1CAFrH5pKN3AMvoM1kIf1CiJhz80VuvFZ9b29wA0u1guePqWmEa+SGwnegYhD16nAW6HTFiN5h/EmZ7A6qFb0qjZVo+tkS4WLiBRqRaKgYnEH8UC7VpCvBjq+iUIVcrfasxJ57Ujc9F42kos1N6u5JjO/Zgkl3/OsLGH7iAK2xAFFOGHAFMsUSZ5dAeYbzZhMzxcwMc8YAOL+mQrPhK4Bw2jyD+t8ZmXwEoUZk3UJM+U6U5LA4PSZdIcVK1kd+QFcEyvy/KiY5pyC9bzRjDuzl/Lvnv8mbRYwTjvk/VwclR3SX5QsDy4xxLxM/gA3J1+YaAIAAA==)